# " error stream.push() after EOF" when using "npm cache verify"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

When I try using "npm cache verify", I get the following error

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/noderuntime/output/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/noderuntime/output/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'cache',
1 verbose cli   'verify' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.1
4 verbose npm-session c361f37acc40114f
5 verbose stack Error: stream.push() after EOF
5 verbose stack     at readableAddChunk (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:264:30)
5 verbose stack     at Class.Readable.push (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:238:10)
5 verbose stack     at Array.from.map.entry (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js:120:29)
5 verbose stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
5 verbose stack     at getKeyToEntry.then.reduced (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js:119:47)
5 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveCallback (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:432:57)
5 verbose stack     at ReductionPromiseArray._resolve (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:61:19)
5 verbose stack     at Promise.completed [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:122:15)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:21)
5 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/noderuntime/output/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
6 verbose cwd /home
7 verbose Linux 3.10.0_3-0-0-15
8 verbose argv "/home/noderuntime/output/bin/node" "/home/noderuntime/output/bin/npm" "cache" "verify"
9 verbose node v8.9.1
10 verbose npm  v5.5.1
11 error stream.push() after EOF
```

Has anyone run into the same problem or any idea why this problem? Please help me! Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try use: `npm cache clean --force`

or

`npm i -g npm@6.9.1-next.0`

Comment: Works only after the first clean for me. Anyway deserves an upvote.